# how to validate date only if date is coming in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I need to validate the format of the date. but the date field is not mandatory. when I left the field blank it checks for the format and throws an error.

```
 'doc_date'       => 'date_format:d-m-Y',
```

Comment: Your question is rather vague - are you validating using the built-in validators in Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying your validator to look like this:

```
'doc_date'       => 'sometimes|date_format:d-m-Y'
```

If the input is always sent, you might try this instead:

```
'doc_date'       => 'filled|date_format:d-m-Y'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-nullable) validator in laravel like this :

```
'doc_date' => 'nullable|date_format:d-m-Y',
```

Comment: Thank you @akshaypjoshi

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the validator to consider null values as invalid, try `nullable` like:

```
'doc_date' => 'nullable|date_format:d-m-Y'
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)

Comment: Thank you Mayak for reference also.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
'doc_date'       => 'nullable|date_format:d-m-Y',
```